# Send image generated from Canvas tag to CFDOCUMENT via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, canvas, coldfusion

I'm attempting to (1) generate an image via canvas, (2) convert it to an image file, (3) post that image file via ajax to a cfc and (4) render it in a CFDocument tag.  At present I have the first three steps working, but when I render the PDF I get a messy string of data.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!  I've shared the code below...

The page...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Image To CFDocument Via toDataURL() and AJAX</title>
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="makePdfLink">Make PDF</a>, <a href="aPdf.pdf">View PDF</a>
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillStyle='#FF0000';
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,80,100);

            $("#makePdfLink").click(function() {    
                var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                var image = new Image();
                image.id = 'pic';
                image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

                var data =  new FormData();
                data.append('pdfBody',image.src);

            $.ajax({
                    url: 'PDF.cfc?method=make',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(results){
                        console.log('success',results);
                    },
                    error: function(results){
                        console.log('error',results);
                    }
                });

            });         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and the CFC...

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="make" access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="any" output="true">
        <cfscript>
            request.acceptExt = 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png';
        </cfscript>
        <cfdocument format="pdf" overwrite="yes" filename="aPdf.pdf" localurl="true">
            <cfdocumentitem type="header">the header</cfdocumentitem> 
            <cfdocumentitem type="footer">the footer</cfdocumentitem> 
            <cfdocumentsection><cfoutput>#pdfBody#</cfoutput>    </cfdocumentsection>    
        </cfdocument>
        <cfreturn SerializeJSON(form) />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Your function does not appear to accept any arguments.  Also, if the intent is to create a pdf, why are you returing anything at all?  I suggest baby steps.  Get the code in your function to work in a .cfm file.  Then put the working code in a function and call it directly from cf.  Only when you have that working should you worry about ajax.

Comment: Does `cfdocument` support the canvas tag?

Comment: Dan, I neglected to add the cfargument tag, but it is accepting the file...or rather a string representation of the file.  As for baby steps I hear you.  James, it does not.

Answer (score 3):

After walking away from this one, scratching my head for a bit and doing a bit more research I have solved the problem!  I am converting the base 64 string and saving it to the filesystem before drawing it in the PDF.  I'm also sharing this solution over at http://www.christophervigliotti.com/2014/05/from-canvas-to-pdf-via-ajax/

```
<cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="make" access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="any" output="true">
    <cfargument name="pdfBody" type="any" required="true" />

    <cfset request.acceptExt = 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' />

    <!--- read the base 64 representation of the image --->
    <cfset cfImageObject = ImageReadBase64(pdfBody) />

    <!--- create a new cf image object --->
    <cfimage source="#cfImageObject#" destination="aPng.png" action="write" overwrite="yes">

    <cfdocument format="pdf" overwrite="yes" filename="aPdf.pdf" localurl="true">
        <cfdocumentitem type="header">the header</cfdocumentitem> 
        <cfdocumentitem type="footer">the footer</cfdocumentitem> 
        <cfdocumentsection>
            <cfoutput>
                <!--- it works! --->
                <img src="aPng.png" />
            </cfoutput>
        </cfdocumentsection>     
    </cfdocument>

    <cfreturn SerializeJSON(form) />
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: What you are returning still seems strange.

Comment: lol just for debugging...the final code will return the file name (which will be generated at runtime)